# Unable to update VM with nodejs app on Google App Engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, gcloud, managed-vm, google-managed-vm

When I try to deploy from the gcloud CLI I get the following error.

```
Copying files to Google Cloud Storage...
Synchronizing files to [gs://staging.logically-abstract-www-site.appspot.com/].
Updating module [default]...\Deleted [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/logically-abstract-www-site/zones/us-central1-f/instances/gae-builder-vm-20151030t150724].
Updating module [default]...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Error Response: [4] Timed out creating VMs.
```

My app.yaml is:

```
runtime: nodejs
vm: true
api_version: 1

automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 2
  max_num_instances: 20
  cool_down_period_sec: 60
  cpu_utilization:
    target_utilization: 0.5
```

and I am logged in successfully and have the correct project ID. I see the new version created in the Cloud Console for App Engine, but the error is after that it seems.

In the stdout log I see both instances go up with the last console.log statement I put in the app after it starts listening on the port, but in the shutdown.log I see "app was unhealthy" and in syslog I see "WARNING: never got healthy response from app, but sending /_ah/start query anyway."

Comment: Hey, this was caused by a production issue over the weekend. It should be fixed now.

Comment: I think I may have figured out what causes this. It turns out that even though my app runs fine locally, it crashes immediately inside the docker image.

This seems to cause the GCE instance to spin endlessly, and in the case of a gcloud deploy, to eventually time out.

Hope that helps!

Comment: @dlorenc I think you were right, thanks for the response and sorry I didn't notice it till now

Comment: it could have been that the health check handler was not configured, looking at the shutdown.log info posted in OP's question

Answer (score 3):

From my experience with nodejs using Google Cloud App Engine, I see that "Timed out creating VMs" is neither a traditional timeout nor does it have to do with creating VMs.  I had found that other errors were reported during the launch of the server --which happens to be right after VMs are created.  So, I recommend checking console output to see if it tells you anything.

To see the console output:

- For a vm instance, then go to [/your/ vm instances](https://console.developers.google.com/project/logically-abstract-www-site/compute/instances) and click the vm instance you want, then scroll towards the bottom and click "*Serial console output*".
- For stdout console logging, go [monitoring /your/ logs](https://console.developers.google.com/project/logically-abstract-www-site/logs) then change the log type dropdown from *Request* to be *stdout*.

I had found differences in the `process.env` when running locally versus in the cloud.  I hope you find your solution too --good luck!